# Read Semi-structured Xml file in Vb.net (Different Nodes/ChildNodes)

Tags: xml, vb.net

i need to extrapolate the data from an xml file through a program written in vb.net. The problem is that the nodes and the child nodes are not all the same, so I can't loop and ask for the elements through the tag name.

How can I read a semi-structured xml file in VB.net?

A small part of the xml file that I have to use (The real file contains many lines, has 10K rows):

```
    <ControlStyles>
    <Id>VariantsDetail.SelectionPanel</Id>
    <PanelStyle>
      <BackColorARGB>-1</BackColorARGB>
    </PanelStyle>
 </ControlStyles>

 <ControlStyles>
    <Id>Report.Base</Id>
    <ButtonStyle>
      <IdFont>SanSerifNormal</IdFont>
      <BackColorARGB>-1513240</BackColorARGB>
      <BorderColorARGB>-5592406</BorderColorARGB>
      <ForeColorARGB>-5658199</ForeColorARGB>
     </ButtonStyle>
     <CheckBoxStyle>
      <IdFont>SanSerifNormal</IdFont>
      <!--Transparent-->
      <BackColorARGB>16777215</BackColorARGB>
      <!--Grigio-->
      <ForeColorARGB>-5658199</ForeColorARGB>
    </CheckBoxStyle>
</ControlStyles>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you select a node (perhaps with XPath) and it is Nothing then it wasn't there, so don't try to process it.

Comment: You should always parse the xml through the tag names. Xml is structure an just reading node you loose the structure. If you xml has a schema the classes can automatically be generated from the schema. – jdweng just now   E

Comment: Not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already tried the System.Xml.Linq namespace? The Load method gives you a root element, then you can iterate using the Descendants() to obtain names and values of elements and attributes.

This just scratches the surface, but something like this:

```
    Dim rootElement = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load("myfile.xml")
    For Each element In rootElement.Descendants
        Console.WriteLine(element.Name.ToString() & "=" & element.Value.ToString())
    Next
```